# How to mock AWS S3 classes using Mockito?

Tags: mockito, junit5

I have the below method, kindly guide me how to mock AWS classes.

```
File saveFileFromS3toDisk(String bucketName, String key) throws IOException {
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
                    .build();
    
            log.info("Downloading file {} from S3.", key);
            S3Object fullObject = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
            surfaceName = fullObject.getObjectMetadata().getUserMetadata().get("surface");
}
```

Comment: why you do not mock this method saveFileFromS3toDisk ?

Comment: Yes i did that. But wanted to increase the test coverage :(